# Sending images through json getting failed

Tags: objective-c, json

```
 Code:

     NSData *imgd=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(Obj.thumbImage, 0.5);
      [imgName insertObject:Obj.imageName atIndex:i];
      [imgName1 insertObject:imgd atIndex:i];
        [dic setObject:imgName forKey:@"name"];
        [dic setObject:imgName1 forKey:@"image"];
        [asiLoadingFormRequest setPostValue:contactName forKey:@"receivername"];
        [asiLoadingFormRequest setPostValue:[dic JSONRepresentation] forKey:@"imagedata"];
```

Is it correct to way sending images through json?When i call server i am getting following error message

```
 "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=1 \"Unsupported value for key image in object\" UserInfo=0x9a611f0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x9a4a290 \"JSON serialisation not supported for NSConcreteMutableData\", NSLocalizedDescription=Unsupported value for key image in object
```

Is it problem with Json that does not support for images?I have no idea about this problem.any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

**Encoding** Part:

First Add [Base64](http://www.imthi.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/base64.zip) class into your project.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:xxx.me.com/me.json"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:100.0];


NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation ([UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: @"ur PNG image path"]);
[Base64 initialize];
NSString *imageString = [Base64 encode:imageData];

NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"image_id",@"image_name","image",nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"22",@"myImageName.png",imageString,nil];

NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary options:kNilOptions error:&error];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

 NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

For **Decoding** the same on the server side(if your using php) refer [this](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send `NSData` as `JSON`, if you want to send an image over `JSON` you have to first encode it in `Base64` and then decode it on the server

Take a look at this 
https://github.com/l4u/NSData-Base64